# Need to make full screen popup in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

I want to open full screen popup but what is happening right now is that from the top it increases but bottom transparent or any color effect is not visible.Below is the code i am using .please let me know where i am wrong.Please see popup design [CLICK HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6NOGV7_pivmcTUtRnRyel9RcjQ/edit?usp=sharing)

```
<Popup  StaysOpen="False" x:Name="popintaling" Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}}"  Placement="Center" IsOpen="False" Height="900"   Panel.ZIndex="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" AllowsTransparency="True" PopupAnimation="Fade" ClipToBounds="True" OpacityMask="#FFFFAA00" RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" >
            <Popup.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect/>
            </Popup.Effect>
            <Border  Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}}" Height="900" BorderBrush="#7F1D1A1A" Margin="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="300,300,300,300" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

                    <Canvas Margin="0,100,0,90"  Height="800" Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.FullPrimaryScreenWidth}}" Panel.ZIndex="999" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#FFF3800C" >
             //some code here
                    </Canvas>

            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

Comment: I got a solution for this.... I set MainWindow Opacity to 0. it makes the background black. it looks like we set border around popup. and fire popup closed event. in this i again set MainWindow Opacity to 100. This really works. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

A **Popup** that covers more than **75 percent** of the screen, reduces its width first and then its height to meet the maximum coverage limit of 75 percent.You cannot cover make it full screen.

Read the documentation : [PlacementMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.placementmode%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for the reply,,but is there any way to get the full screen pop up by making any structural design change,that i have posted above

Answer (score 1):

after InitializeComponent in constructor, set popup child width and height from code

```
(popintaling.Child as FrameworkElement).Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
(popintaling.Child as FrameworkElement).Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
```

Answer (score 0):

A full screen popup is not a popup. Just put that code into a border with a Background color  and handle the events yourself. Also to make your App fullscreen just set the *WindowState* to *Maximized*, and the *WindowStyle* to *None*